# e17 installation and unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, updates, software-installation, dependencies, enlightenment

Every which way I try to correct unmet dependencies it gives me some long error.
Trying to install packages I get

```
evas-loaders : Depends: libefl (>= 201312241217) but it is not going to be installed
libedbus1 : Depends: libefl (>= 201312241217) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try to open `software-proporties-gtk` its a grey icon that cannot be opened. Trying *Synaptic package manager* to fix broken packages `evas-loaders/libedbus1` it says

```
Failed to fetch http://packages.enlightenment.org/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/Release.gpg
Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.enlightenment.**org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

and another thirty something like that.

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: In the second error message it looks like you are trying to install packages intended for Jaunty Jackalope (aka Ubuntu 9.04). If you are indeed using this ancient version, please be aware that it is no longer supported by either Ubuntu or this site. On the other hand, if you are using a recent version of Ubuntu it is not surprising that you get dependency errors by the dozen when trying to install packages for a 5-year-old version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I had problems with enlightenment, because I didn't install the stable version. I had to use Synaptic, go through libs manually, and do apt-get clean, and apt-get autoclean, and a bunch of other things.

I am not sure if you are using version 9.04 of Ubuntu, if you are not you installed an older version (Jaunty).

The newest stable versions of enlightenment are for v. 12.04 -- 13.10. https://launchpad.net/~efl/+archive/trunk

If you are not 9.04, you will need to redo your repositories, this can be done in Synaptic Package Manager by looking at your repository lists, or you can use the terminal if you know what repositories you pointed to.

[How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Add the stable repository for enlightenment.

If you really want to, and just can't remove everything, look in your /lib for files that start with 'libe' check online to see what each one is, if it is associated with enlightenment (save it in a different folder), then delete it.

Add the stable repository for enlightenment. Then do sudo apt-get update.

Hopefully I didn't miss a step.